# change property of jquery plugin TableExport.js

Tags: jquery, plugins, prototype

I am trying to change the buttonContent property of a plugin that I am using - https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/

The plugin page says that each button is assigned a default class and default content based on its respective filetype and corresponding css styles. Here's the prototype -

```
$.fn.tableExport.xlsx = {
    defaultClass: "xlsx",
    buttonContent: "Export to xlsx",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    fileExtension: ".xlsx"
};
```

Here's how it is implemented -

```
$("table").tableExport({
    headings: true,
    footers: true,
    formats: ["xls", "csv", "txt"],
    fileName: "id",
    bootstrap: true,
    position: "bottom"
    ignoreRows: null,
    ignoreCols: null,
    ignoreCSS: ".tableexport-ignore"
});
```

**I need help in changing the buttonContent**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`$.extend($.fn.tableExport.xlsx, {buttonContent: 'My Content'})`

Then

```
$('table').tableExport(options) // options object
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical approach for customizing or extending the prototype of [`TableExport`](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport), or any JavaScript/jQuery plugin for that matter, is as follows:

```
// jQuery ($.fn.NAME.PROP)
$.fn.tableExport.xlsx.buttonContent = 'My Content';

// or

// JavaScript (NAME.prototype.PROP)
TableExport.prototype.xlsx.buttonConten = 'My Content';
```

> **Note:** this will work for *any* of the other plugin setting as well (e.g. **defaultFileName**, **defaultFileName**, **defaultButton**, **rowDel**, **colDel**, etc.)

You can find all of the usage documentation in the [README](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport) on github or on the [TableExport](https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/) website.

> **P.S.** I am the plugin author **;)**

Comment: Hi @Travis can you help me to include css while exporting table? my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386683/keep-style-format-while-uploading-table-to-excel-via-tableexport-js