# Keep style format while uploading table to excel via TableExport.js

Tags: javascript, export, export-to-excel

I'm using `TableExport.js` to export my `html` table to `Excel` file. I can able to export the table but In the excel sheet the `css` are failing. Help me to  achieve this problem. I'm using `inline` css only. I've attached my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table2csv Plugin</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- <link href="css/table2csv.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.0/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/5.0.0/css/tableexport.css"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/5.0.0/js/tableexport.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="Population-list">
    <caption><h2>Countries by population</h2></caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th  bgcolor="#00FF00">Rank</th>
        <th  bgcolor="#00FF00">Country</th>
        <th  bgcolor="#00FF00">Population</th>
        <th  bgcolor="#00FF00">% of world population</th>
        <th  bgcolor="#00FF00">Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td  bgcolor="#00FF00">China</td>
        <td>1,370,570,000</td>
        <td>18.9%</td>
        <td>June 24, 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td  bgcolor="#00FF00">India</td>
        <td>1,273,140,000</td>
        <td>17.6%</td>
        <td>June 24, 2015</td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td  bgcolor="#00FF00">Bangladesh</td>
        <td>126,880,000</td>
        <td>2.19%</td>
        <td>June 24, 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>




<script>
    TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), {
    headers: true,                              // (Boolean), display table headers (th or td elements) in the <thead>, (default: true)
    footers: true,                              // (Boolean), display table footers (th or td elements) in the <tfoot>, (default: false)
    formats: ['xlsx', 'csv', 'txt'],            // (String[]), filetype(s) for the export, (default: ['xlsx', 'csv', 'txt'])
    filename: 'id',                             // (id, String), filename for the downloaded file, (default: 'id')
    bootstrap: false,                           // (Boolean), style buttons using bootstrap, (default: true)
    exportButtons: true,                        // (Boolean), automatically generate the built-in export buttons for each of the specified formats (default: true)
    position: 'bottom',                         // (top, bottom), position of the caption element relative to table, (default: 'bottom')
    ignoreRows: null,                           // (Number, Number[]), row indices to exclude from the exported file(s) (default: null)
    ignoreCols: null,                           // (Number, Number[]), column indices to exclude from the exported file(s) (default: null)
    trimWhitespace: true                        // (Boolean), remove all leading/trailing newlines, spaces, and tabs from cell text in the exported file(s) (default: false)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are referring to applying CSS styles (e.g. colors, margins) to the exported spreadsheet itself, unfortunately, that is not implemented. The styles only apply to the html and do not transfer to the xlsx document. If you are referring to styles to the html table refer to https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport/issues/151

Comment: Oh! My bad luck. Can you suggest me something to achieve my goal?

Comment: Under the hood, TableExport leverages https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx to parse and write the xlsx document and this library does, in fact, support cell styling (to a degree). If a library does not already exist that implements this, then It would require either working directly with [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) or adding support to TableExport itself.

Comment: okay thanks for suggestion.